# Derive the Concavity of Quantum Conditional Entropy from Strong subadditivity

Tags: textbook-and-exercises, nielsen-and-chuang, linear-algebra, entropy

In [Exercise 11.25, Page 522, Entropy and information, Quantum Computation and Quantum Information by Nielsen and Chuang](http://mmrc.amss.cas.cn/tlb/201702/W020170224608149940643.pdf), it is required to show that the concavity of the conditional entropy may be deduced from strong subadditivity by introducing an auxiliary system $R$ into the problem.

My understanding about the concavity of the conditional entropy is that, if $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$ are quantum bipartite states of the system $AB$ and $\lambda\in[0,1]$ then
$$
S(A|B)_{\lambda\rho_1+(1-\lambda)\rho_2}\ge\lambda S(A|B)_{\rho_1}+(1-\lambda)S(A|B)_{\rho_2}
$$
The strong subadditivity is given by the inequality, $S(A,B,C)+S(B)\le S(A,B)+S(B,C)$

We can possibly use the properties:
$$
\rho\text{ is a pure state}\iff S(\rho)=0\\
AB\text{ is a pure state}\implies S(A)=S(B)\\
S(A|B)=S(A,B)-S(B)\\
$$

If we introduce an auxiliary system $R$ to purify our quantum system $ABC$ such that $\rho^{ABCR}$ is a pure state, then
$$
S(A,B,C)=S(R)
$$

It'd be helpful if one can point me in the right direction to obtain the concavity condition of the relative quantum entropy.

**Note:** Concavity of Conditional Entropy can be shown from the Joint Convexity of Relative Entropy

---

**My Attempt**

We have $\rho^{AB}=\lambda\rho_1^{AB}+(1-\lambda)\rho_2^{AB}$ and it is required to prove that,
$$
S(A|B)_{\lambda\rho_1+(1-\lambda)\rho_2}\ge\lambda S(A|B)_{\rho_1}+(1-\lambda)S(A|B)_{\rho_2}\\
S(A|B)_{\rho^{AB}}\ge\sum_i p_iS(A|B)_{\rho^{AB}_i}
$$

**Lemma:** Suppose $p_i$ are probabilities, $|i\rangle$ are orthogonal states for a system $A$, and $\rho_i$ is any set of density operators for another system $B$, then
$$
S(\sum_ip_i\rho_i\otimes |i\rangle\langle i|)=H(p_i)+\sum_i p_iS(\rho_i)
$$
proof:
$$
\rho_{AB}=\sum_ip_i\rho_i\otimes |i\rangle\langle i|\quad\&\quad \rho_i|\lambda_i^j\rangle=\lambda_i^j|\lambda_i^j\rangle\\
(\rho_i\otimes|i\rangle\langle i|)(|\lambda_i^j\rangle\otimes |i\rangle)=\rho_i|\lambda_i^j\rangle\otimes|i\rangle=\lambda_i^j(|\lambda_i^j\rangle\otimes|i\rangle)\\
\rho_{AB}(|\lambda_i^j\rangle\otimes|i\rangle)=(\sum_ip_i\rho_i\otimes |i\rangle\langle i|)(|\lambda_i^j\rangle\otimes |i\rangle)=p_i\lambda_i^j(|\lambda_i^j\rangle\otimes |i\rangle)\\
$$
$\implies$ The eigenvectors of $\rho_{AB}=\sum_ip_i\rho_i\otimes |i\rangle\langle i|$ are $|i\rangle\otimes|\lambda_i^j\rangle$ with eigenvalue $p_i\lambda_i^j$.
\begin{align}
S(\sum_ip_i\rho_i\otimes |i\rangle\langle i|)&=-\sum_{i,j} p_i\lambda_i^j\log (p_i\lambda_i^j)\\
&=-\sum_{i,j}p_i\lambda_i^j(\log p_i+\log\lambda_i^j)\\
&=-\sum_ip_i\log p_i\sum_j\lambda_i^j-\sum_i p_i\sum_j\lambda_i^j\log\lambda_i^j\\
&=-\sum_i p_i\log p_i-\sum_i p_i\sum_j\lambda_i^j\log\lambda_i^j\\
&=H(p_i)+\sum_i p_iS(\rho_i)
\end{align}

---

The strong subadditivity is,
$$
S(A,B,X)+S(B)\le S(A,B)+S(B,X)\\
S(A,B,X)-S(B,X)\le S(A,B)-S(B)\\
S(A|B)\ge S(A|B,X)\\
$$
$$
S(A|B)\ge S(A|B,X)=S(A,B,X)-S(B,X)\\
$$
$$
\rho^{AB}=\sum_i p_i\rho_i^{AB}\implies\rho^{ABX}=\sum_i p_i\rho_i^{AB}\otimes|i\rangle\langle i|\\
\implies \rho^{BX}=tr_A\big(\sum_i p_i\rho_i^{AB}\otimes|i\rangle\langle i|\Big)=\sum_i p_itr_A\Big(\rho_i^{AB}\otimes|i\rangle\langle i|\Big)=\sum_i p_i\Big(\rho_i^{B}\otimes|i\rangle\langle i|\Big)
$$

Using lemma,
$$
S(A,B,X)=S(\rho^{ABX})=S(\sum_i p_i\rho_i^{AB}\otimes|i\rangle\langle i|)=H(p_i)+\sum_i p_iS(\rho_i^{AB})\\
S(B,X)=S(\sum_i p_i\rho_i^B\otimes |i\rangle\langle i|)=H(p_i)+\sum_i p_iS(\rho_i^{B})
$$
Substituting into the result of the strong subadditivity gives,
\begin{align}
S(A|B)\ge S(A|B,X)&=S(A,B,X)-S(B,X)\\
&=S(\rho^{ABX})-S(\rho^{BX})\\
&=H(p_i)+\sum_i p_iS(\rho_i^{AB})-H(p_i)-\sum_i p_iS(\rho_i^{B})\\
&=\sum_i p_iS(\rho_i^{AB})-\sum_i p_iS(\rho_i^{B})\\
&=\sum_i p_i\Big(S(\rho_i^{AB})-S(\rho_i^{B})\Big)\\
&=\sum_i p_iS(A|B)_{\rho^{AB}_i}\\
\end{align}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You start with a two bipartite states $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$ on a system $AB$. Their convex mixture with parameter $\lambda \in [0,1]$ is another quantum state
$$\rho_{AB} = \lambda \rho_1 + (1-\lambda)\rho_2$$
on $AB$. Operationally, this state corresponds to preparing $\rho_1$ with probability $\lambda$ and $\rho_2$ with probability $(1-\lambda)$ and then forgetting which state you prepared.

If we don't forget what state we prepared then we can describe the state of the system in the following way. We have a classical register $X$ where we record which state we prepared $1$ or $2$. Then the state of the whole system $XAB$ is
$$
\rho_{XAB} =\lambda |1\rangle\langle 1|\otimes \rho_1 + (1-\lambda)|2\rangle \langle 2 |\otimes \rho_2.
$$
Notice if we trace out the system $X$ (forget about the preparation) we recover the convex mixture above.

Now for your question, I will give you a hint but let you finish the details. By strong subadditivity you know that
$$
H(A|B) \geq H(A|BX).
$$
I would then try to think about how you can simplify the RHS knowing that $X$ is a classical system.

Comment: Thanks for your hint. I have tried to follow the proof in my attempt section in the post. Could you please have a look?

Comment: Looks fine to me

Answer (score 1):

A concise rewriting of what has already been said: consider $\rho=\sum_i p_i \rho_i$ with $\sum_i p_i=1$, $p_i\ge0$. Here $\rho_i$ are bipartite states, with the spaces labelled with $A$ and $B$. We want to prove that
$$S(A|B)_\rho \ge \sum_i p_i S(A|B)_{\rho_i}.$$
Start observing that the strong subadditivity of the von Neumann entropy is equivalent to the statement $S(A|B)_\rho \ge S(A|BX)_\rho$, for any $\rho\equiv\rho_{ABX}$, and spaces $A,B,X$.
Apply this to the state
$$\rho_{ABX}=\sum_i p_i (\rho_i\otimes |i\rangle\!\langle i|).$$
This gives $\rho_{AB}=\sum_i p_i \rho_i$, and
$$S(A|BX) = \sum_i \operatorname{Prob}(X=i) S(A|B, X=i)_\rho
= \sum_i p_i S(A|B)_{\rho_i},$$
which concludes the proof.